# Use an LDR to run a sketch

Tags: led, sketch

This may sound like a simple question but I have tried to find the right solution but all I find is the usual make an led blink and even I can code that nugget
I am quite new to programming arduino but am a dab hand with a soldering iron.
What I would like to do is combine the attributes of an LDR to allow a lighting sketch to run if it is dark and go off in daylight, but all I seem to find is turn a pin high or low, this is no good as I already have a sketch I would like to run

I am using WS2811 led nodes housed in pinspot style housings so the sketch would need to check the light level and if it is below a set value run the rest of the sketch then check every hour to see if the light level has changed to be above a set level  if it is go into a check loop until the light level falls again to below the set value can anyone point me in the right direction I would be grateful for any assistance

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Can you show us the "lighting" sketch you written?

Comment: It sounds like you need to put your light code in an if statement that checks the light level.  I know I’ve seen this project done over and over so I don’t believe you can’t find an example.  If you find one that just sets a pin high or low in response to the ldr then you’re almost there.  Just take out the line that turns the pin high or low and replace with code that turns your led strip on or off.  It’s really just that simple.

Comment: the function that reads the value of an LDR and the function that turns on the lights are two completely separate functions ... the LDR function raises a flag that says `light on` ... it does nothing else .... the light function turns on the light if it sees the flag .... it does nothing else .... the `light on` flag could also be raised by a pushbutton being pressed or by a timer or by sound detector hearing noise, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You're unlikely to find exactly what you want as existing code example. Break it into parts and solve it in parts.

You can't "Run a sketch" based on reading a value of an LDR. You can write a new sketch that reads an LDR, and calls a function if it's dark, or a different function if it is light. You will need to refactor your code from your other sketch into functions that you can integrate into your new combined sketch that uses the LDR. That means doing some original programming, not "finding the right solution" ready-made on the internet.

First, how do you use an LDR to determine if it's light or dark? Answer, use an analog input. Build a voltage divider with the LDR and a similar sized resistor, and feed the output into an analog pin. Say the LDR is between +5V and the pin, so more light results in higher voltage, hence a larger value.

Log the output of the LDR to the console in a loop, and decide on your threshold values for light and dark. Make the threshold value a constant. Let's call it DARK.

Now write a loop function. It might look something like this:

```
int lightValue;
#define ldr_pin xxx //your pin number
#define threshold xxx //your threshold value

void setup() {
   //set the ldr pin as an analog input
}

void loop() {
   lightValue = analogRead(ldr_pin);
   if (lightValue <= threshold) {
      doNightStuff();
   } else {
      stopDoingStuff();
   }
}
```

### Edit:

As mentioned by Edgar, the code above will be subject to "jitter", where it will rapidly switch back and forth between the dark and light states.

The solution is to add a buffer range where once it's in one state, it doesn't change states until it leaves the buffer range.

The if statement might look like this:

```
#define buffer 5

if ((lightValue +buffer) <= threshold) 
    doNightStuff(); 
else if ((lightValue -buffer) >= threshold) 
    stopDoingStuff();
```

Comment: It would be still better with two thresholds that provide some hysteresis.

Comment: Fair point, but I think that might be beyond the OP's current level of understanding.

Comment: You are probably right. OTOH, without hysteresis, the OP is likely to be coming back here pretty soon. :-)

Comment: if you power the LDR with an INPUT_PULLUP pin instead of VIN, you don't need a fixed resistor to form your divider, just plug the other LDR lead into the analog input. This won't give you full range, but it's more than enough resolution to distinguish dark from light.

Comment: simple adding of hysteresis, replace all loop code but first line: `if ((lightValue +5) <= threshold) doNightStuff();
if ((lightValue -5) >= threshold) stopDoingStuff();` Adjust as needed.

Answer (score -1):

@ Duncan C

think i have a solution not sure if it's your way but it does work so not bad for a newbie lol

```
//
//  "Pacifica"
//  Gentle, blue-green ocean waves.
//  December 2019, Mark Kriegsman and Mary Corey March.
//  For Dan.
//  Thanks for the sketch i have added a daylight sensor so they now go off in daylight Dave Cowell June 2020

int lightValue;  //new code dc

#define FASTLED_ALLOW_INTERRUPTS 0
#include <FastLED.h>
FASTLED_USING_NAMESPACE


#define ldr_pin             A0   //new dc
#define Threshold_dark      100  //new dc
#define Threshold_light     1000  //new dc
#define DATA_PIN            7
#define NUM_LEDS            28
#define MAX_POWER_MILLIAMPS 500
#define LED_TYPE            WS2811
#define COLOR_ORDER         RGB

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

void setup() {

  analogRead (A0);  //new dc
 
  delay( 3000); // 3 second delay for boot recovery, and a moment of silence
  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE,DATA_PIN,COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS)
        .setCorrection( TypicalLEDStrip );
  FastLED.setMaxPowerInVoltsAndMilliamps( 5, MAX_POWER_MILLIAMPS);
}

void loop(){

 lightValue = analogRead (ldr_pin);  //new dc

 if (lightValue <= Threshold_dark){    // new dc

    EVERY_N_MILLISECONDS(20)     
    pacifica_loop();
    FastLED.show();
  
 }else { (lightValue = Threshold_light);  // New dc

 {                                         // New dc

 for (int i = 0; i <NUM_LEDS;i++){         // New dc

      memset (leds,0,NUM_LEDS*3);          // New dc

 
                FastLED.show();             // New dc

                FastLED.delay (100);         // New dc

 }         // New dc
  }        // New dc      
   }       // New dc
    }      // New dc



 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The code for this animation is more complicated than other examples, and 
// while it is "ready to run", and documented in general, it is probably not 
// the best starting point for learning.  Nevertheless, it does illustrate some
// useful techniques.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// In this animation, there are four "layers" of waves of light.  
//
// Each layer moves independently, and each is scaled separately.
//
// All four wave layers are added together on top of each other, and then 
// another filter is applied that adds "whitecaps" of brightness where the 
// waves line up with each other more.  Finally, another pass is taken
// over the led array to 'deepen' (dim) the blues and greens.
//
// The speed and scale and motion each layer varies slowly within independent 
// hand-chosen ranges, which is why the code has a lot of low-speed 'beatsin8' functions
// with a lot of oddly specific numeric ranges.
//
// These three custom blue-green color palettes were inspired by the colors found in
// the waters off the southern coast of California, https://goo.gl/maps/QQgd97jjHesHZVxQ7
//
CRGBPalette16 pacifica_palette_1 = 
    { 0x000507, 0x000409, 0x00030B, 0x00030D, 0x000210, 0x000212, 0x000114, 0x000117, 
      0x000019, 0x00001C, 0x000026, 0x000031, 0x00003B, 0x000046, 0x14554B, 0x28AA50 };
CRGBPalette16 pacifica_palette_2 = 
    { 0x000507, 0x000409, 0x00030B, 0x00030D, 0x000210, 0x000212, 0x000114, 0x000117, 
      0x000019, 0x00001C, 0x000026, 0x000031, 0x00003B, 0x000046, 0x0C5F52, 0x19BE5F };
CRGBPalette16 pacifica_palette_3 = 
    { 0x000208, 0x00030E, 0x000514, 0x00061A, 0x000820, 0x000927, 0x000B2D, 0x000C33, 
      0x000E39, 0x001040, 0x001450, 0x001860, 0x001C70, 0x002080, 0x1040BF, 0x2060FF };


void pacifica_loop()
{
  // Increment the four "color index start" counters, one for each wave layer.
  // Each is incremented at a different speed, and the speeds vary over time.
  static uint16_t sCIStart1, sCIStart2, sCIStart3, sCIStart4;
  static uint32_t sLastms = 0;
  uint32_t ms = GET_MILLIS();
  uint32_t deltams = ms - sLastms;
  sLastms = ms;
  uint16_t speedfactor1 = beatsin16(3, 179, 269);
  uint16_t speedfactor2 = beatsin16(4, 179, 269);
  uint32_t deltams1 = (deltams * speedfactor1) / 256;
  uint32_t deltams2 = (deltams * speedfactor2) / 256;
  uint32_t deltams21 = (deltams1 + deltams2) / 2;
  sCIStart1 += (deltams1 * beatsin88(1011,10,13));
  sCIStart2 -= (deltams21 * beatsin88(777,8,11));
  sCIStart3 -= (deltams1 * beatsin88(501,5,7));
  sCIStart4 -= (deltams2 * beatsin88(257,4,6));

  // Clear out the LED array to a dim background blue-green
  fill_solid( leds, NUM_LEDS, CRGB( 2, 6, 10));

  // Render each of four layers, with different scales and speeds, that vary over time
  pacifica_one_layer( pacifica_palette_1, sCIStart1, beatsin16( 3, 11 * 256, 14 * 256), beatsin8( 10, 70, 130), 0-beat16( 301) );
  pacifica_one_layer( pacifica_palette_2, sCIStart2, beatsin16( 4,  6 * 256,  9 * 256), beatsin8( 17, 40,  80), beat16( 401) );
  pacifica_one_layer( pacifica_palette_3, sCIStart3, 6 * 256, beatsin8( 9, 10,38), 0-beat16(503));
  pacifica_one_layer( pacifica_palette_3, sCIStart4, 5 * 256, beatsin8( 8, 10,28), beat16(601));

  // Add brighter 'whitecaps' where the waves lines up more
  pacifica_add_whitecaps();

  // Deepen the blues and greens a bit
  pacifica_deepen_colors();
}

// Add one layer of waves into the led array
void pacifica_one_layer( CRGBPalette16 & p, uint16_t cistart, uint16_t wavescale, uint8_t bri, uint16_t ioff)
{
  uint16_t ci = cistart;
  uint16_t waveangle = ioff;
  uint16_t wavescale_half = (wavescale / 2) + 20;
  for( uint16_t i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    waveangle += 250;
    uint16_t s16 = sin16( waveangle ) + 32768;
    uint16_t cs = scale16( s16 , wavescale_half ) + wavescale_half;
    ci += cs;
    uint16_t sindex16 = sin16( ci) + 32768;
    uint8_t sindex8 = scale16( sindex16, 240);
    CRGB c = ColorFromPalette( p, sindex8, bri, LINEARBLEND);
    leds[i] += c;
  }
}

// Add extra 'white' to areas where the four layers of light have lined up brightly
void pacifica_add_whitecaps()
{
  uint8_t basethreshold = beatsin8( 9, 55, 65);
  uint8_t wave = beat8( 7 );
  
  for( uint16_t i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    uint8_t threshold = scale8( sin8( wave), 20) + basethreshold;
    wave += 7;
    uint8_t l = leds[i].getAverageLight();
    if( l > threshold) {
      uint8_t overage = l - threshold;
      uint8_t overage2 = qadd8( overage, overage);
      leds[i] += CRGB( overage, overage2, qadd8( overage2, overage2));
    }
  }
}

// Deepen the blues and greens
void pacifica_deepen_colors()
{
  for( uint16_t i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    leds[i].blue = scale8( leds[i].blue,  145); 
    leds[i].green= scale8( leds[i].green, 200); 
    leds[i] |= CRGB( 2, 5, 7);
  }
  {

  }
}
```